# About the C++ overloaded operators

Tags: c++, operators

Running the program below on my computer

```
#include <iostream>

class Int {
public:
  Int(int x) : val{x} {}
  Int operator++() {
    std::cout << "Int::operator++()\n";
    return ++val;
  }
  friend Int operator+(Int a, Int b) {
    std::cout << "operator+(Int, Int)\n";
    return a.val + b.val;
  }
  friend Int operator*(Int a, Int b) {
    std::cout << "operator*(Int, Int)\n";
    return a.val * b.val;
  }

private:
  int val;
};

int main()
{
  Int a = 1, b = 2;
  b = ++a + b * b;
  return 0;
}
```

I got this output:

```
operator*(Int, Int)
Int::operator++()
operator+(Int, Int)
```

As far as I known, the prefix `++` has higher precedence than binary `*`. But in the output shown above, the prefix `++` is called **after** the binary `*`! Is it because the compiler treats the operator+ as a function call (which leads to Unspecified Behavior)? Can I always consider an overloaded operator as a function (which makes the behavior of `x = x++` well-defined when `x` is an `Int`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Precedence affects grouping, not order of evaluation.   Yes, `++` has high precedence than `*` (for multiplication),  so the expression `++a + b * b` is equivalent to `(++a) + (b * b)`.   However, the order of evaluation of operands for `+` is unspecified, so there is no guarantee that `b*b` will be evaluated before or after `++a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because the compiler treats the `operator+` as a function call (which leads to Unspecified Behavior)?

Yes. But note that it doesn't matter if `++a` is evaluated after `b * b`, because in the end, those two are added correctly, which respects operator precedence rules.

Your expression without the assignment is equivalent to:

```
operator+(a.operator++(), operator*(b, b))
```

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified, so technically, `++a` can be evaluated before `b * b`, but also the other way around.

> Can I always consider an overloaded operator as a function (which makes the behavior of `x = x++` well-defined when `x` is an `Int`)?

Yes and no. If `Int` does the same thing as the "normal" operators would do, then no (until C++17), because that would be undefined behavior. But if `Int` doesn't change `x` in `x++` for example, then yes.

Comment: "The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified" That's not a good prospect, b might be a function call which changes a somehow, which might have very different results than with a different input. Imagine the case when b = ln(a). In that case we have a non-commutative expression and the result will be different if the evaluation order is different.

Comment: @M.M that's a direct conclusion, but an unnecessary limitation.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I known, the prefix `++` has higher precedence than binary `*`.

Higher precedence doesn't mean that the prefix increment will be called before the multiplication operator, but in which order the parameters are bound to the corresponding operation.